# Dynamic Table Bucketing

Tags: database, dynamic, rows, bucket

I've scoured the net, but I can't find a solution that *quite* solves my current problem. I want the *user* to be able to group table rows based on the values of columns. They should be collapsible, too.

Example data:

```
Size   Number   Place   Name
----   ------   -----   ----
S      10       NY      First
S      15       NY      Another
S      20       DE      Second
M      10       NY      Third
L      4        DE      Fourth
```

The user should then be able to see a list of the columns (Size, Number, Place) and drag them onto the vertical axis. This will then automatically group the rows by similar column values. The user should also be able to specify a hierarchy, such as Place -> Size -> Name. Here would be an example of that:

```
                  Number
---------------------------
(-) NY            35 [sum]
    (-) S          25
         First      10
         Another    15
    (-) M          10
         Third      10
(-) DE            24
    (-) S          20
         Second     20
    (-) L          4
         Fourth     4
```

Collapsing, say, NY would obviously show:

```
                  Number
---------------------------
(+) NY            35
(-) DE            24
    (-) S          20
        Second      20
    (-) L          4
        Fourth      4
```

The trick here is that the user should be able to simply rearrange the order, and it will rebucket it. So if they then wanted to see Size -> Place -> Name...:

```
                  Number
---------------------------
(-) S             35
    (-) NY         25
         First      10
         Another    15
    (-) DE         20
         Second     20
(-) M             10
    (-) NY         10
         Third      10
(-) L             4
    (-) DE         4
         Fourth     4
```

Hopefully that makes sense. Does anyone have an idea of a good way to do this? I don't care about the architecture of the database - assume I can get it into whatever form is necessary (i.e. calling it with PHP from MySQL, grabbing it out of a CSV with Perl, anything). The front-end is what I'm concerned about mostly.

Comment: look up PIVOT, or Pivot Table

Comment: Sorry I should have made this more clear - this is to be done in HTML, and the "user" is the site user.

Answer (score 0):

If you are needing to do this in HTML then I guess https://github.com/mauriciosantos/buckets this will help you. You can use Multi dictionary for ur case. Its free and it supports browsers from IE6.All the best :-)